# MySQL tables are not accessible but are visible

Tags: mysql, macos

In OSX, I have installed MySQL using Homebrew. The trouble is that MySQL starts fine in system startup but the tables in the schema are not accessible. The tables are been shown in show tables command but not accessible when I run a query.

Another important point to note is that once MySQL is restarted - it works perfectly well. What might the cause be. MySQL version is 5.6.16.

Comment: "The tables are been shown in show tables command but not accessible when I run a query." What error do you get?

Comment: Sounds like you updated privileges with `UPDATE mysql.user ...` but didn't do `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams it states that the tables cannot be found http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-find-table.html

Comment: @BillKarwin I don't think so. I am using it as the `root` user